# different signature_def input keys with tensorflow DDNClassifier export model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator) quick start guide. My model is trained and I added following snippet to export the model

```
export_path_base = sys.argv[-1]
export_path = os.path.join("export",export_path_base)

INPUT_TENSOR_NAME = 'x'

def serving_input_receiver_fn():
feature_spec = {INPUT_TENSOR_NAME: tf.FixedLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[6])}
return tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)()

classifier.export_savedmodel(export_path, serving_input_receiver_fn)

print('model is exported')
```

with this my model is exported properly without any error. But when I am trying to verify my model with following command

```
saved_model_cli show --dir export\estimator_one\1508656267 --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default
```

it is not showing any input named as `'x'`, instead it is showing the following list

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: input_example_tensor:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1, 3)
    name: dnn/head/Tile:0
outputs['scores'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 3)
    name: dnn/head/predictions/probabilities:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/classify
```

am I doing something wrong or missing here? can someone please point out.

Comment: I took a look at the quick start guide, and the input shape is different. Are you sure it's [6], and not [4]?

Comment: @KathyWu , I am using some different data that contains 6 features, that's why in my code shape is [6]. But I believe that would create a problem if I pass wrong argument during serving. But how that could impact input name? why it is not showing 'x' as an input name?